# How do I migrate Entity Framework and LocalDB connections to Azure SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

I have the following EF and Local DB connection strings

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DirectTrustIssuerBilling.mdf;Initial Catalog=DirectTrustIssuerBilling;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PaymentsModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.PaymentsModel.csdl|res://*/Data.PaymentsModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.PaymentsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DirectTrustIssuerBilling.mdf;initial catalog=DirectTrustIssuerBilling;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I've already created the server and database in the azure portal. Also I found connection strings in the portal for ADO.NET and others.

[image]

---

**Question**

1. If I don't care about the data, already configured the firewall, and just want to change my connection strings so that this on premise app will work in the cloud, what must I do?
2. If I want to save this password in App Settings (in the portal), or key vault, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using EF6.x, then there's nothing to do other than change your connection strings. TO find the connection string that you need to use that's already formatted, go to your Azure SQL management blade in the portal. On the overview tab, there will be a link that reads "Show database connection strings". This will give you what you need to replace in your web.config.

Note that EF 6.x already has retry logic built in to handle any transient failure you may experience connecting to an Azure SQL instance.

If you would rather save your connection string (with password) in the portal, navigate to your web app's management blade, and choose the "Application Settings" menu option under the Settings heading. You can enter your connection strings here. App settings and connection strings defined in the portal will override whatever is specified in your web.config for your app.